# fnPageChange not working without delay? JS sequence error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sequence, datatables

I'm running into a strange issue, and it's happening across a few sites I maintain that use datatables.

Whenever I utilize fnPageChange, it does not work unless there is a setTimeout around it like this;

```
setTimeout(function() { oTable.fnPageChange(whatPage); }, 100);
```

or with an alert before it

```
alert('starting'); oTable.fnPageChange('last');
```

I understand this may be a sequence error of some sort, but I'm just unsure why the same issue would arise across multiple projects.

Here is the delete function I'm working with now:

```
function fnDelete(elem){
    if (selected.length>0) {
        var c;
        c = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected ${displayTableName}?');
        if (c) {
            // Create delete url from editor url...
            var deleteURL = (urlstr.substring(0, urlstr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)) + "delete.do";
            deleteRecord(deleteURL,selected[0]);

            if ( $('tableViewer tr').length === 0) {
                // Reload the Table
                oTable.fnPageChange('last');
                //Send them back to the last page
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what kind of issue this might be?

Here is deleteRecord:

```
function deleteRecord(deleteURL, iid){
    var didDelete = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: deleteURL,
            dataType:"html",
            data:"recordID="+iid,
            success:function(response){
                didDelete = true;
                oTable.fnDraw(true);
                selected = [];
                selectedRecord = [];
                enableButtons(selected);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                if ((xhr.status >=400) && (xhr.status < 500))
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                else
                    alert('error');
            }    
        });

    return didDelete;
}
```

Comment: Somehow I suppose `deleteRecord` is asynchronous, am I right? )

Comment: I think so? I've added the function to the question -- would that be the problem? I'm still working on my ajax lol

Comment: Ya, set "async:false," in your ajax config request

Comment: Yes, it's the problem. That `if ( $('tableViewer tr').length === 0)` line won't wait for your ajax call to finish _unless_ you put it out of the common sequence (with setTimeout or alert) as well.

Comment: Oh okay. I added 'async:false," right under the ajax type, but it's still not working? Is there another area in the ajax call where I should place it or is there then something else going on here (perhaps a second synced ajax call or something)?

Comment: Is there anything new on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can try as below to

```
oTable.page(CurrentPageNo).draw(false);
```

Here, oTable is object of Datatable.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to change a page. OP already uses `fnPageChange` method from DataTables 1.9 which is the same as `page` method in DataTables 1.10.